# PaintComponent not rendering image?

Tags: java, graphics

I'm trying to display a small 16x16 pixel image to a JPanel. I've written a simple function that creates and returns a BufferedImage object that I'm then trying to pass to paintComponent, however, nothing is rendering when I launch the program (with no errors being printed to the console). Help?

Thanks!

```
    
    public BufferedImage loadImage(String filePath) {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(filePath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            
        }
        return img;
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(loadImage("/resources/tile.png"), 0, 0, this);
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens when you print the IOException (e.printStackTrace();)?

Comment: Don't do I/O in a painting method. A painting method should be efficient since you can't control when it is called. The image should be read in the constructor of your class. Also, how is the panel added to the frame. Does the panel have a size? Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

we can also use the below source code inside paintComponent to draw an image swing.

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Toolkit t=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Image image=t.getImage(<path of image>);
    g.drawImage(image, 0,0,this);
}
```

where,

img - the specified image to be drawn. This method does nothing if img is null.
x - the x coordinate.
y - the y coordinate.
observer - object to be notified as more of the image is converted.

in case to load an bufferImage, you can also check the below link contains good amount of details.
https://www.baeldung.com/java-images

Thanks